# SQL - join but like R vector recycling

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's two tables.  They're kinda like this.

```
create temp table l (k int, v int);
create temp table r (k int, v int);
insert into l values 
   (1, 11),
   (2, 21), (2, 22),
   (3, 31),
   (4, 41), (4, 42), (4, 43), (4, 44),
   (5, 51), (5, 52),
   (6, 61), (6, 62), (6, 63);
insert into r values
   (1, 101),
   (2, 201),
   (3, 301), (3, 302),
   (4, 401), (4, 402), (4, 403),
   (5, 501), (5, 502), (5, 503),
   (6, 601), (6, 602), (6, 603);
```

If I do a simple inner join of these tables on the `k` column, I get the Cartesian product for row groups 4 through 6.  Is there any way to get, instead, behavior not entirely unlike [vector recycling](https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/vectorization_recycling_and_indexing.html#recycling) in [R](https://www.r-project.org/)?  Concretely, the desired joined table is something like

```
=> select l.k, l.v as lv, r.v as rv from l, r
->  where l.k = r.k and /* additional condition that does what I want */;
 k | lv | rv
---+----+-----
 1 | 11 | 101

 2 | 21 | 201
 2 | 22 | 201

 3 | 31 | 301
 3 | 31 | 302

 4 | 41 | 401
 4 | 42 | 402
 4 | 43 | 403
 4 | 44 | 401

 5 | 51 | 501
 5 | 52 | 502
 5 | 51 | 503

 6 | 61 | 601
 6 | 62 | 602
 6 | 63 | 603
```

And the desired behavior in English is: For each group of rows defined by `l.k = r.k`, arbitrarily associate each value from the left side with a *single* value from the right side.  If the sides are not the same size, repeat just enough values from the smaller side to pair each value from the larger side with one value from the smaller.  Either side may be the larger one.

(In case it matters: The real join will produce order of ten million row groups, the largest row group has order of 10 values on the larger side, and roughly 80% of all row groups are either 1:N or M:1.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

- Enumerate the rows for each `k` in each table.
- Count the rows for each `k` in each table.
- When there is a `NULL` value, fill it in with the filled-in value using "enumeration % count" *for the other value*.

As SQL, this looks like:

```
select k,
       coalesce(l.v, max(l.v) over (partition by k, r.seqnum % l_cnt.l_cnt)),
       coalesce(r.v, max(r.v) over (partition by k, l.seqnum % r_cnt.r_cnt))
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by k order by random()) as seqnum
      from l
     ) l full join
     (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by k order by random()) as seqnum
      from r
     ) r
     using (k, seqnum) full join
     (select k, count(*) as l_cnt
      from l
      group by k
     ) l_cnt
     using (k) full join
     (select k, count(*) as r_cnt
      from r
      group by k
     ) r_cnt
     using (k)
order by k;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a0a08cb51ac3876d0c97360858ec5742) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that `max(row_number()) = count(*)` but this code leaves NULLs in each output row group where the two sides' sizes are not equal (in the example data, all groups except 1 and 6).  What is desired is to _repeat_ arbitrarily selected values from the smaller side to fill in any gaps.

Comment: @zwol . . . I'm not sure why I thought the first version worked.  I replaced it, following the logic that is described.